# No-Explicit solution of parametric solutions of an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the solution in parametric form of the following ODE:
$$y(x) y'(x)-y(x)=\frac{A}{x},  A\in \mathbb{R}$$
[The same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329724/solve-x-y-fracdydx-left-fracdydx-right2/329899#329899)

I found solution in this [Book](http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf) on page 134. (example 16).
[image]

Let $F(x,y,t)=y t-y-\frac{A}{x},$

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{ty}{\frac{A}{x^2}+t(-1+t)}=-\dfrac{ty}{\frac{A}{x^2}-t+t^2)}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{y}{\frac{A}{x^2}+t(-1+t)}=-\dfrac{y}{\frac{A}{x^2}-t+t^2)}$

And what Next?

Comment: the homogenous problem is solved by$C x$

Comment: the solution contains the error-function